# C# Convert String to DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime, converters

i have string token[5] = Aug and string token[6]=1 (see on image[image: token])

i want to convert to DateTime.

i try:

```
DateTime DateCreated = DateTime.ParseExact(tokens[5] + tokens[6], "MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: And it's MMM for shorthand string, MM is two-digit month numbers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a few issues:

- You were missing the expected hyphen "-" from the built string `tokens[5] + tokens[6]`.
- Your `MM` would expect a two-digit month, for a three letter shorthand month use `MMM`.
- Finally, your `dd` expects a two-digit day (so in your case, 01 instead of 1). Use `d` to take one- or two-digit days.

With all this said and done, you don't actually *need* the hyphen:

```
var dateCreated = DateTime.ParseExact(tokens[5] + tokens[6], "MMMd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Refer to this MSDN entry for more options:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Comment: thanks you, but i got error:The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Comment: @user609511 That'd be what happens when the format differs from the string you give it (so the parsing fails), what was the format you used and what was the string you gave it? Given your "Aug1" from above, my proposed format will work so you are likely inputting different strings or using a different format.